# How to get a value from a c# datatable and pass it to javascript

Tags: c#, javascript

I know this is easy for a good number of people but please bear with me I am kind of new to javascript.

I want to pass a value from a cell in a system.data datatable to javascript so i can plot graphs with the data from the datatable using javascript.

Comment: Are you using WebForms or MVC, or simply a WebService invoked by Ajax from the client side?

Answer (score 0):

add a `HiddenField` to the page markup, call it `hid1` for example, then:

```
hid1.Value = dt("FirstName") & "," & dt("LastName") ....
```

then from javascript:

```
var hid1 = document.getElementById('hid1');
var values = hid1.innerHTML.split(',');
```

then loop over values... or do something...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to populate the variable:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "whateverkey", "varName = 'var value';", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's quite a few ways to do it, the simplest one being hidden fields. You can set the hidden field in asp.net and then read it in jscript, something like:

in .aspx:

```
<script>
  var value=$("#<%= hdfData.ClientID %>").val(); // using jQuery for example
</script>


<input type=hidden id=hdfData>
```

in .aspx.cs

```
void SomeInitMethod()
{
  hdfData.Value=........;
}
```

You could also directly databind the value if the script is inside your form.